# Get data response from fetch when is created as javascript module in my code

Tags: javascript, flask, fetch

I have been trying for a days that a function created as a module can return the data.

I use flask and in a page I am loading the module in the header.

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'js/modules.js')}}"></script>
```

In my first attempt in the modules.js file I have this function:

```
function send_to_backend_old(data){

let coucou = fetch('/toronto', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(function(response) {
    response.json().then(function(data_received) {

        return data_received;
        
    }).then((data_received)=>{
        return data_received;
    })

});

return coucou
```

In the html page within the javascript part when I call the function this data does not arrive.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="pruebas_fetch_to_backend();">fetch módulo</button>


function pruebas_fetch_to_backend(){


        let datos_json = {};
        datos_json.url_api = '/toronto'
        datos_json.test1 = 'valor1'
        datos_json.test2 = 'valor2'



        
        console.log("---------------------------------------------")
        riri = send_to_backend(datos_json)
        console.log("valor de riri: "+JSON.stringify(riri))
        console.log("---------------------------------------------")

    }
```

the other test is as follows:

```
async function send_to_backend(data) {
    let apiResponse = await fetch("/toronto", {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
    let response = apiResponse.json();
    // Since we waited for our API to respond using await
    // The response variable will return the response from the API
    // And not a promise.
    console.log(response);
    return  Promise.all(response);
}
```

How can I get the response when I call the function from the javascript code in the html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions like `fetch(...)` and `.json()` are asynchronous functions. These return an object of type Promise. This means that the result of the function is not returned immediately.
With `await` the final result can be awaited and can then be used. Functions that use the await keyword must be defined as asynchronous.

```js
async function sendFetchRequest() {
  const data = await fetchJSONData({
    test1: 'value1',
    test2: 'value2'
  });
  console.log(data);
}
```

As an alternative to `await`, however, a callback function can also be passed to a `.then(...)` call. Then a synchronous function can also be used to call an asynchronous function.
In this case, a synchronous function returns a `Promise` object resulting from the callback of the asynchronous fetch call. The returned object is then awaited in the above function and dumped after getting the final result.

```js
function fetchJSONData(data) {
  return fetch('/echo', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(resp => {
    return resp.ok && resp.json()
  });
}
```

In order to catch an error, there is the option of using a try-catch block, as well as the use of a callback within `.catch(...)`.

So a simple example would look like this.

###### JS (static/js/module.js)

```js
function fetchJSONData(data) {
  return fetch('/echo', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(resp => {
    return resp.ok && resp.json()
  });
}
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/module.js')}}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="sendFetchRequest()">Click me!</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function sendFetchRequest() {
        const data = await fetchJSONData({
          test1: 'value1',
          test2: 'value2'
        });
        console.log(data);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    jsonify,
    render_template,
    request,
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/echo')
def echo():
    return jsonify(request.json)
```

Comment: speechless. wow! This is exactly the result I was looking for, thank you very much!